# How can I access parameters passed in the URL when a form is POSTed to my script?

Tags: perl, post, parameters, cgi, get

I've run into an issue with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) when submitting forms to our site perl scripts. If someone does a GET request on a page with a url such as `http://www.example.com/us/florida/page-title`, I rewrite that using the following rewrite rule which works correctly:

```
RewriteRule ^us/(.*)/(.*)$ /cgi-bin/script.pl?action=Display&state=$1&page=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Now, if that page had a form on it I'd like to do a form post to the same url and have Mod Rewrite use the same rewrite rule to call the same script and invoke the same action. However, what's happening is that the rewrite rule is being triggered, the correct script is being called and all form POST variables are being posted, however, the rewritten parameters (action, state & page in this example) aren't being passed to the Perl script. I'm accessing these variables using the same Perl code for both the GET and POST requests:

```
use CGI;
$query = new CGI;
$action = $query->param('action');
$state = $query->param('state');
$page = $query->param('page');
```

I included the QSA flag since I figured that might resolve the issue but it didn't. If I do a POST directly to the script URL then everything works correctly. I'd appreciate any help in figuring out why this isn't currently working. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're doing a POST query, you need to use [`$query->url_param('action')`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI#MIXING_POST_AND_URL_PARAMETERS) etc. to get parameters from the query string.  You don't need or benefit from the QSA modifier.

Comment: $query->url_param() did the trick. I was dumping the $query param initially to try to see if it was being passed to CGI.pm but I guess that parameters in the POST URL aren't actually part of the $query object. Interesting but at least I now have the solution. Thanks for the quick response Sinan!

Comment: @Russell C. I think you should be thanking @chaos. Now, who downvoted my answer?

Comment: Well, don't I get any thanks for actually linking his answer to the docs? ***I am joking***

Comment: Thanks Sinan. :)  And yeah, what's the deal with the downvoting on this question?  Harsh, yo.

Answer (score 3):

Change your script to:

```
use CGI;
use Data::Dumper;

my $query = CGI->new; # even though I'd rather call the object $cgi
print $query->header('text/plain'), Dumper($query);
```

and take a look at what is being passed to your script and update your question with that information.

Comment: -1 that prepares a response, it doesn't show the input. The input query string comes from the environment variable QUERY_STRING.

Comment: @Kinopiko Look at the output in front of you. The parameters that will be in that `$cgi` object will only be the parameters passed via post, not via the URL. That ought to then spark something that says ... hmmmm ... maybe the problem is not with `mod_rewrite`. *How do I access the parameter passed in the URL when the form I am processing was POSTed?* Let me see the CGI docs. Admittedly more indirect than `@chaos`s answer but still leading the OP in the right direction. Now, if you do not understand what is in the `$cgi` object, then that is a completely different matter.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I didn't notice the Dumper ($query) part.